# Checkmarx SQL injection high severity issue

Tags: java, spring, security, sql-injection

I am getting a high severity issue in this method:

```
    public void recordBadLogin(final String uid, final String reason, final String ip) throws DataAccessException {
    if (Utils.isEmpty(uid)) {
        throw new DataAccessException("User information needed to update , Empty user information passed");
    }
    try {
        String sql = (String) this.queries.get(IUtilDAO.queryKeyPrefix + UtilDAO.RECORD_FAILED_LOGIN);
        Map<String, Object> paramMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        paramMap.put("uid", uid.trim());
        paramMap.put("reason", (reason != null ? reason.trim() : "Invalid userid/password"));
        paramMap.put("ip", ip);
        this.namedJdbcTemplate.update(sql, paramMap);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new DataAccessException("Failed to record bad login for user " + uid, e);
    }
}
```

This line of code is causing the issue:

```
String sql = (String) this.queries.get(IUtilDAO.queryKeyPrefix + UtilDAO.RECORD_FAILED_LOGIN);
```

queries is a properties object and the prepared statement is being retrieved given IUtilDAO.queryKeyPrefix + UtilDAO.RECORD_FAILED_LOGIN. And those 2 arguments are constants. Logically I don't see how this can cause an SQL injection issue as the prepared statement is being retrieved from a dictionary. Does anyone have an idea if this is a false positive or if there is an actual vulnerability present?

Comment: It may get confused because of the concatenation operation. But that's very non-idiomatic code. Is there a reason the query is in a map and not as a constant in the method or class?

Comment: Its in a properties file that contains all the queries that the application uses

Comment: Well, that's not a very good approach. Instead of keeping the queries where they're used, they're grouped together into a property file, which is the wrong place for SQL queries. The approach is fragile, but it's not an attack vector for SQL injection.

Comment: I guess I should overhaul it or ignore the checkmarx warnings. Thanks kayaman. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell from the example given, but I'd guess that the properties object was tainted by untrusted data.  Most code flow analysis tools will taint the entire data structure if any untrusted data is placed in it.

Technically this is a "false positive".  But architecturally it's something that should be fixed - it's generally a bad idea to mix trusted and untrusted data together in the same data structure.  It makes it easy for future developers to misunderstand the status of a particular element, and makes it harder for both humans and tools to code review for security issues.